# Run bash script from another script without waiting for script to finish executing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

Is there any way to execute two bash scripts without the first one blocking? The following does not work:

```
exec ./script1.sh #this blocks!
exec ./script2.sh
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Put `&` at the end of the line.

```
./script1.sh & #this doesn't blocks!
./script2.sh
```

Comment: Can we know when the first one is finished as well?

Comment: Typically, you will get a line that looks like this when the first script backgrounds itself: `[1] 6209` Where the number in the `[]`s is the job number and the second number is the process ID.  Later on you'll get `[1]+  Done` when the first process finishes.  To list your running jobs you can use the `jobs` command.  To prevent a job from canceling if you log out you can `disown` it.  To pause the script until your job completes you can use the `wait` command.  For more information see the [job control](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) pages from the bash manual.

Comment: What if the process doesn't not give up the terminal e.g Mongodb.  What do I do?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do in that case is launch it in a tmux session, and then clean up the tmux sessions later.

Comment: Actually, looking at the man pages for mongo, can't you just use the `--eval` flag to launch a specific script non-interactively?

Comment: We had another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641916/when-using-exec-with-the-final-command-does-not-run caused by someone taking this answer to imply that `exec` was something they could use in their script without knowing/understanding its behavior and limitations. Insofar as `exec` isn't needed for *any* of the desired behavior here, consider taking it out, or at least adding some commentary?

Comment: Sure I will remove it

Answer (score 7):

Run the first one in background using `&` and you should be good.