# When using exec with &, the final command does not run

Tags: bash, unix

It seems the code after `if`/`fi` is not running.  Here is what I have:

I have a script, /my/scripts/dir/directoryPercentFull.sh:

```
directoryPercentFull="$(df | grep '/aDir/anotherDir' | grep -o '...%' | sed 's/%//g' | sed 's/ //g')"
if [ $directoryPercentFull -gt 90 ]
then
    echo $directoryPercentFull
    exec /someDir/someOtherDir/test01.sh &
    exec /someDir/someOtherOtherDir/test02.sh &
    exec /someDir/yetAnotherDir/test03.sh
fi

echo "Processing Done"
```

The scripts being called are:
/someDir/someOtherDir/test01.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "inside test01.sh"
sleep 5
echo "leaving test01.sh"
```

/someDir/someOtherOtherDir/test02.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "inside test02.sh"
sleep 5
echo "leaving test02.sh"
```

/someDir/yetAnotherDir/test03.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "inside test03.sh"
sleep 5
echo "leaving test03.sh"
```

running the script by cd-ing to /my/scripts/dir and then doing ./directoryPercentFull.sh gives:
OUTPUT:

```
93
inside test03.sh
inside test02.sh
inside test01.sh
leaving test03.sh
leaving test01.sh
leaving test02.sh
```

OUTPUT EXPECTED:

```
93
inside test01.sh
inside test02.sh
inside test03.sh
leaving test01.sh
leaving test02.sh
leaving test03.sh
Processing Done
```

The order of the echo commands are not that big of a deal, though if someone knows why they go 3,2,1, then 3,1,2, I wouldn't hate an explanation.

However, I am not getting that final `Processing Done`.  Anyone have any clue why the final `echo` back in `/my/scripts/dir/directoryPercentFull.sh` does not occur?  I have purposefully not placed an `&` after the last `exec` statement, as I don't want what what is after the `if`/`fi` to run until all of it is finished processing.

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `exec echo 1; echo 2`.

Comment: You don’t need to use exec to run commands, remove these exec, from the beginning of each line, invoke the scripts directly.

Comment: @melpomene, I did think I new what exec was doing.  I found this on stackoverflow and assumed it was valid to do so: [Run bash script from another script without waiting for script to finish executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183805)

Comment: The linked answer only happens to work because the `&`-less `exec` is the last command in the script. It shouldn't have those `exec`s and the answerer ought to have mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/someDir/someOtherDir/test01.sh &
/someDir/someOtherOtherDir/test02.sh &
/someDir/yetAnotherDir/test03.sh
```

Get rid of all the `exec`s. `exec` causes the shell process to be **replaced** by the given command, meaning the shell does not continue executing further commands.

> The order of the echo commands are not that big of a deal, though if someone knows why they go 3,2,1, then 3,1,2, I wouldn't hate an explanation.

The printouts could come in any order. The three scripts are run in parallel processes so there's no telling which order they `echo` their printouts.

Comment: @RoryLatham, ...as John says, the outputs are unordered; just because the output ordering comes out in a given way in one run (or in a set of runs performed under a given level of system load &c) doesn't mean it'll behave that way consistently. It's like dictionary order in Python; it might *look* consistent if you're testing a specific way, but if it isn't *guaranteed* to be consistent, writing code that assumes otherwise is going to bite you.